# React / Neovis.js: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS

Tags: reactjs, websocket, neo4j

So I have this react application that uses Neovis.js it's a graph visualization plugin for Neo4j database, and it works fine in development, but when I deploy it to Heroku the plugin doesn't work and it shows this messages in the console:

`DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.`

And this: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxxxxxxx.com/person/20' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://xxxxxx:7687/'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.`

I've seen posts on this error so I downgraded my react-scripts in package.json from 4.0.1 to 3.2.0 like they said , but after that there was too many deprecated stuff and the whole app didn't work in Heroku.

I also tried to edit webPackHotDevClient.js line 62 to : `protocol: window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws'` but still not working.

By the way, the neo4j endpoint is on Http not https, should my neo4j endpoint be accessible with https?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :**

One solution i found myself is to access the heroku app with `http://` and not `https://` so that my plugin in my react app can talk with the neo4j instance that's running on `http` , not the best answer but it works !

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using a ternary operator to check the current environment protocol:

My Neovis config:

```
const vis = new Neovis({
  server_url: 'neo4j://myHost:myPort',
  ... // Additional config
  encrypted: window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'ENCRYPTION_ON': 'ENCRYPTION_OFF',
});
```